# Collect all 'name'-fields from Google Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Google Firebase Realtime Database with the following structure:

```
project
|
 - users
   |
    - uid_1
      |
       - name
       - age
       - ...
   |
    - uid_2
      |
       - name
       - age
       - ...
```

I'm new with Google Firebase. I can read all db-fields from a specific 'uid'. But how can I collect all names from all unsers? I want to make an file-uploader and to assing the file to an existing user, I want to use a dropdown-menu to select the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way you have this data structured, you're going to have to write code to query everything under "users", iterate the children, and pull the names out of each child.

Realtime Database doesn't offer any sort of SQL-like projection type query that will get you just the vales of certain children.  Or to put it another way, you can't do anything like "select name from users".  If getting only the name is a common operation for you, you will need to duplicate only the names into another parent node, and query that new node instead.

Comment: Guess duplicating only the names into another parent node should work... I'll give it a try!

Comment: I can confirm: it works :-) Thank you @Doug Stevenson

Answer (score 0):

The [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add-sdk) allows [retrieving the entire list of users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.BaseAuth#listusers) in batches. But max result is 1000.

Or you can [denormalizing](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) your [data](https://youtu.be/vKqXSZLLnHA).